# Edit SSRS report within Dynamics AX 2012 TEST environment

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Ok so in the LIVE instance of AX - I go to the AOT, find my report, right click edit. This then launches VS and I can edit the report. However in the TEST environment I cannot do the same. " Unable to connect to the AOS specified in the Microsoft Dynamics AX Client Configuration".

How to I point the TEST environment to VS? I've checked the config file but nothing obvious there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See how to [Open Visual Studio with a Specific Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889291.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> If you are working with reports, the Visual Studio integration uses the active local client configuration to establish the connection. Examples that require a Reporting Services configuration include deploying a report or selecting a query as a data source. To point to the correct AOS in this scenario, create a copy of the configuration file in the Visual Studio integration folder.

In order to start VS for a specific change the VS shortcut target to point to correct configuration:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /AxConfig ContosoDev
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /AxConfig z:\Config\ContosoDev.axc
```

This will not work from the AOT of cause, VS will then use the current configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look [here](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/120699). It has to do with using the default configuration instead of the AXC file.

There is a KB, although it may not be for your version, you can apply the technique used:

> KB 2827469 Visual Studio .NET launched from within AOT overlooks
>   AxConfig parameter and any custom config profile.   When open VS
>   Project from AOT SysVSProjectsExport/EditProject() method executes and
>   it calls the below VSModeling framework Edit method where it is
>   passing only the selected solution to the devenv.exe file. But since
>   the current AXClient instance is opened from a saved configuration
>   file, we have to pass that configuration file to devenv.exe as a
>   switch "/AxConfig". As this /AxConfig switch is not considered Visual
>   Studio default considering active AxClient configuration from system
>   registry.

So:

> Try to open AX from the default configuration and avoid to use the
>   AXC file. Then, try to edit a VS Project from AOT.